# Problems with the linear span of the empty set

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the span of the empty list $()$ or the empty $Ø$ set is defined to be the 'zero vector', what i don't get, is, the zero vector from what space? because all vector spaces contain the empty set, so $ span() = {0} = {(0,0)} = {(0,0,0)} = ...  $ and so on, but clearly $  0 ≠ (0,0) ≠ (0,0,0) $ and so on. I'm really stuck on this. Hope someone understands my question. Thanks in advcance.

Comment: What is the span of a set without referencing a vector space?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404379/span-of-an-empty-list?rq=1) has a good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "span", you have to specify the vector space $V$ you are talking about.  To be completely formal, you would write $\operatorname{span}_V$.  Often the $V$ is understood from context and we just write $\operatorname{span}$, but you should remember that it's always there.

Answer (score 2):

"Span" only makes sense with respect to a given vector space.  $\operatorname{span}\{ \emptyset\}$  is defined with respect to an underlying space, so whatever the zero vector is in the given space.